# Using flocker volumes, Whether or not be installed Powerstrip?

Tags: kubernetes

I am using flocker volumes. Should I install Powerstrip?   I have installed flocker, but not installed Powerstrip. I create flocker pod fail:

> Unable to mount volumes for pod "flocker-web-3gy69_default": Get
>   https://localhost:4523/v1/configuration/datasets: x509: certificate is
>   valid for control-service, hostname, not localhost.

I have set `FLOCKER_CONTROL_SERVICE_BASE_URL` and `MY_NETWORK_IDENTITY` in flocker-docker-plugin.service file.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to install Powerstrip anymore. (it's been deprecated)

Powerstrip was a useful tool early on to prototype docker extensions but we've moved on since Docker has added the docker api via the plugins model. (Powerstrip was essentially a Precurser to docker plugins)
`docker --volume-driver=flocker`
`docker volume create --name -d flocker`

If you have the docker plugin installed you should be fine.
instructions on manual plugin setup are located here

http://doc-dev.clusterhq.com/install/install-node.html

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/17651  flocker version:1.7.1  k8s version: 1.1.2.  I have set related env variables on all nodes.

Create flocker-pod.yml (kubernetes/examples/flocker/flocker-pod.yml) fail. 
kubectl describe pods flocker-web-j1pld

Error syncing pod, skipping: Get https://localhost:4523/v1/configuration/datasets: x509: certificate is valid for control-service, my-hostname, not localhost